# Python 2D Array Unexpected Overwrite

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am simplifying a use case, but given a 2D array I'd like to overwrite the first column with the value of i at each column. However instead of overwriting a single cell, it is overwriting the entire column at every step.

```
array = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [[0,0,0]]
for i in range(3):
    array[i][0] = i+1
    print(array)
```

Expected Output:

```
[[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [[0,0,0]]
[[1,0,0], [2,0,0], [[0,0,0]]
[[1,0,0], [2,0,0], [[3,0,0]]
```

Actual Output:

```
[[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0]]
[[2,0,0], [2,0,0], [2,0,0]]
[[3,0,0], [3,0,0], [3,0,0]]
```

I suspect calling range() is somehow effecting this but I do not know why. Please help explain why accessing a single cell overwrites the entire column each time!

Comment: How are you creating the list of lists? It looks like you are assigning the same list to all 3 positions in the containing list

Comment: Because the three lists are pointing to the same reference in memory it is overwriting? What is the proper initialization then. I did '''height * [width * [0]]" to create a 2D array of zeros.

Comment: Try `[[0] * width for _ in range(height)]`

Comment: That worked thanks, what is the difference?

Comment: Your method was creating a list with 3 references to the same list, when you print `array` you are just printing the same list 3 times, when you modify `array[0]` you are modifying `array[1]` and `array[2]` too. My method above creates 3 separate list objects

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution (minus the extra square bracket on the first line) and I have your expected result. So you may have to think about how about you build your input array.

```py
input_array = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
for i in range(3):
    input_array[i][0] = i + 1
    print(input_array)
```

[image: Demonstration]

Another solution with the same answer:

```py
input_array = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
for (i, line) in enumerate(input_array):
    line[0] = i + 1
    print(input_array)
```

[image: Other demonstration]